# why we need EndInvoke() to return value of asynchronous call in delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates

i am having a bit trouble in understanding it that BeginInvoke() method call in a delegate when asynchronously calls methods, after completion of it's tasks why can't BeginInvoke() itself return the return value from the method, why we require EndInvoke() to query BeginInvoke() and return the return value from it.
i know this may be not a good query, but my confusion is real :-)

Addition: i can call a method asynchronously using DelagateName.BeginInvoke(parameters), now when the matching method in the delegate(suppose it returns a value) finishes it's work and returns a value, why i need DelegateName.EndInvoke() to get the returned value? why can't the first call itself can return value on method completion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `BeginInvoke` returns, the method hasn't finished - that's the whole point of it being asynchronous. So `BeginInvoke` can only give you a token representing the "promise" of a result at some point - and you use that promise to get the *actual* result using `EndInvoke`, usually in a callback.

In .NET 4 this is more pleasantly encapsulated using [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) of course, but generics weren't part of .NET 1, hence the somewhat more convoluted approach for delegates.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that really solves my query :-), i think in layman's language BeginInvoke is done on getting call and returned the control back with a promise of taking care of the Job, so it can not do any returning work anymore, hence EndInvoke() will be neded to do that job later... (I guess i am thinking right !)

Comment: @mohits00691: Not quite how I'd express it, but I think you've got the right idea :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, helped me a lot to clear this doubt, i guess with time i shall keep on diving more and more, Thanks a lot everybody.

Answer (score 8):

You only need the `BeginInvoke` and matching `EndInvoke` if you are wanting to call the delegate asynchronously i.e. it won't block the current thread. This is useful for long running methods or methods that call processes that you don't control e.g. across application boundaries.

From what you describe you may be better off using the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method which will return the value within the same method - and on the same thread i.e. synchronously. Of course your thread could be blocked by a long running process in this instance. It depends what your are trying to do.